# ArcGIS web app not starting

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, deployment, ssl

I'm trying to make a test application using ArcGIS Web AppBuilder, I built the app downloaded it,and unzipped it, tried to launch it using IIS not working and the same thing by nodejs's http-server, it loads for moments then I get this error message "GET /headless-content.js.map" Error (404): "Not found", I tried to locate this file but never found it. Also in the browser I noticed that it stop working after a message 'redirecting http to https' so I edited all urls in the config.json to http but still having same issue.
Any tips how to find out what causes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable HTTPS on my web server (IIS) https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/enabling_ssl_in_iis.htm